# Can't verify Email and Password data from Firebase Auth

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

So I've linked my app to a Firebase project and I've created a login form. I'm trying to get the data from the Email and Password inputs and verify it with whats in the Firebase project but for some reason the data isn't being received by Firebase, I was able to achieve it perfectly earlier but now I don't know whats going on...

**App.js**

```
import style from "./auth.module.css";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { auth, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithGoogle, registerWithEmailAndPassword } from "../../firebase";
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";


const Auth = () => {
  const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState("main");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(auth);

  const Emailform = () => {
    return (
      <div className={style.formBox}>
        <label className={style.label}>Email:</label>
        <form className={style.input}>
          <input 
            type="email" 
            name="email" 
            required="true"
            />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  
  const Passform = () => {
    return (
      <div className={style.formBox}>
        <label className={style.label}>Password:</label>
  
        <form className={style.input}>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            name="password" 
            required="true" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  let domNode = useClickOutside(() => {
    setActiveMenu(false);
  });

  return (
    <div className={style.container}>
      <Login />
      <Signup />
    </div>
  );

  function AuthType(props) {
    return (
      <a
        href={props.link}
        className={style.menuItem}
        onClick={() => props.goToMenu && setActiveMenu(props.goToMenu)}
      >
        {props.children}
      </a>
    );
  }


/* Login */
  function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    return (
      <CSSTransition in={activeMenu === "main"} unmountOnExit timeout={500}>
        <div ref={domNode}>
          <div className={style.login}>
            <h1 className={style.title}>Clip It</h1>
            {/* Email and Password */}
            <Emailform value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <Passform value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>

            <div className={style.button}>
              <input 
                type="submit" 
                value="Login"
                onClick={() => signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)} />
              <input 
                type="submit" 
                value="Login with Google"
                onClick={signInWithGoogle} />
            </div>
            <div className={style.text}>
              <p className={style.plink}>Forgot Password</p>
              <div>
                Need an account?&nbsp;
                <AuthType goToMenu="Signup">click here</AuthType>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
    );
  }


  /* SignUp/Register */
  function Signup() {
    return (
      <CSSTransition in={activeMenu === "Signup"} unmountOnExit timeout={500}>
        <div ref={domNode}>
          <div className={style.signUp}>
            <div className={style.title}> Clip It</div>
            <Form label="First Name" type="text" />
            <Form label="Last Name" type="Text" />
            <Emailform value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}/>
            <Form label="Date of Birth" type="date" />
            <Passform value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}/>
            <Form label="Confirm Password" type="password" />
            <div className={style.button}>
              <input 
                type="submit" 
                value="Sign Up"
                onClick={registerWithEmailAndPassword} />
            </div>
            <div className={style.text}>
              have an&nbsp;
              <AuthType goToMenu="main"> account</AuthType>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
    );
  }
}
let useClickOutside = (handler) => {
  let domNode = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let clickListener = (event) => {
      if (domNode.current && !domNode.current.contains(event.target)) {
        handler();
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("mousedown", clickListener);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", clickListener);
    };
  });
  return domNode;
};

function Form(props) {
  return (
    <div className={style.formBox}>
      <label className={style.label}>{props.label}:</label>

      <form className={style.input}>
        <input 
          type={props.input} 
          name={props.input} 
          required="true" />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Auth;
```

**Firebase.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
//import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/auth"
import "firebase/firestore"

// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional 
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCq8BAlTWJXG7rFU95QkUTU8U0kXruPA9o",
  authDomain: "clip-it-70ff5.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://clip-it-70ff5-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "clip-it-70ff5",
  storageBucket: "clip-it-70ff5.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "637963668511",
  appId: "1:637963668511:web:9cbd1deae03b819153d92a",
  measurementId: "G-8S1G78ZH49"
};

const app = !firebase.apps.length ? firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : firebase.app();

const auth = app.auth();
const db = app.firestore();


/* Using Google Authentication */
const googleProvider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
//
  const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithPopup(googleProvider).then((res) => {
        const user = res.user;
        const userName = user.displayName;

        alert("You're logged in " + userName);
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };


  /* Using Email and Password */
  // Sign/Logging In
  const signInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.trim(), password);
      alert("You've logged in successfuly");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert("The email or password is incorrect, please try again");
    }
  };

  //SigningUp
  const registerWithEmailAndPassword = async (email, password) => {
    try {
      const res = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      const user = res.user;
      await db.collection("users").add({
        uid: user.uid,
        authProvider: "local",
        email,
      });
      alert("New user added!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };

  //Sending Password reset link
  const sendPasswordResetEmail = async (email) => {
    try {
      await auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
      alert("Password reset link sent!");
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      alert(err.message);
    }
  };

  const logout = () => {
    auth.signOut();
  }; // Log out

  export {
    signInWithGoogle,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    registerWithEmailAndPassword,
    sendPasswordResetEmail,
    logout,
    auth,
    db,
  };
```

Comment: I checked your code it's look right, can you send the repo url or codesandbox url so I can guide you properly.

Comment: Problem is, the repo is private so I wouldn't be able to do that necessarily... So I'm not sure how else we can figure this out...

Comment: Please make it public first

Comment: Ok, here is the repo URL: https://github.com/JojoDuke/newclip

Answer (score 0):

You're still assigning props to your Emailform/Passform components in your Login component which you never actually access. So you're never actually setting the state of email or password.

Remove all of the props and rewrite Emailform/Passform like this:

```
  const Emailform = () => {
    return (
      <div className={style.formBox}>
        <label className={style.label}>Email:</label>
        <form className={style.input}>
          <input 
            type="email" 
            name="email" 
            required="true"
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  const Passform = () => {
    return (
      <div className={style.formBox}>
        <label className={style.label}>Password:</label>
  
        <form className={style.input}>
          <input 
            type="password" 
            name="password" 
            required="true" 
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Now this actually works. But the only problem is, once the Onchange is passed it causes the components to rerender anytime there's a change in the inputs so I can only type one letter at a time, and I don't want that...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by only being allowed to type one letter at a time, can you upload a gif of what you're seeing? When a state is updated, React re-renders components depending on that state, so the re-rendering isn't an issue in of itself.